# ErrorAccessDenied when try to get/set messagerules API using Microsoft Graph

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I tried get/set the outlook rules using messagerules, the Microsoft Graph API call. It's working for my mailbox without any problem. When i tried doing for other user mailboxes it's failing with error

> "code: ErrorAccessDenied", "message:Access is denied. Check
> credentials and try again".

I set delegated permissions for the app, passed correct credentials, still it's failing. How to investigate and fix this issue? Any guidance would be of help.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use delegated permissions when you want to access the other user mailbox?

Comment: Thanks @Dev for helping me in this one too. I am new to Graph API, so i just followed Microsoft documentation. Tried delegated permission for my app, it was working for my mailbox. So i was expecting it should work when i try calling other mailboxes too? Am i doing wrong?

Comment: For your scenario, you should use application permission instead of delegated permission. Let me explain a bit. Some apps call Microsoft Graph using their own identity and not on behalf of a user. They can be background services or daemon apps that run on a server without the presence of a signed-in user. These apps make use of OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow to authenticate and are configured with application permissions, which enable such apps to access all mailboxes in a organization on Exchange Online.

Comment: Thanks again @Dev. Now i understand it and i believe this will work. Do you have any sample/guidance how to implement it? Also share me the steps how i test it with tool like POSTMAN?

Comment: Yes @Alice, here you go. The related documentation/steps available @ - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow (yes, you can test this via POSTMAN too - detailed steps are given in the documentation itself) as well. Test it out, let me know, how it goes

Comment: Yes, you can test this via POSTMAN too - detailed steps are given in the above documentation itself!!

Comment: I think i have enough info now. Will test the above and hopefully it work for me. Thanks @Dev for your valuable help.

Comment: Great news. I tested the steps as per the documentation. POSTMAN works for me. Issue resolved. Awesome 'MasterDev' for your assistance again!!

Comment: Glad @Alice that the above steps/info helped. I will move this to answer - so it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For your scenario, you should use application permission instead of delegated permission, as it won't work for you.
- Let me explain a bit. Some apps call Microsoft Graph using their own
  identity and not on behalf of a user. They can be background services
  or daemon apps that run on a server without the presence of a
  signed-in user. These apps make use of OAuth 2.0 client credentials
  grant flow to authenticate and are configured with application
  permissions, which enable such apps to access all mailboxes in a
  organization on Exchange Online.
- The related [documentation/steps available @ link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) (yes, you can test this via POSTMAN too - detailed steps are given in the documentation itself) as well
- You tested it out, confirmed the steps working for you!!